# Django2.0 and dynamic formsets jquery - delete not recognized after form submission

Tags: jquery, django, inline-formset

In a Django 2.0 project, I am trying to implement a view using an inline formset to create/edit/delete three metric values belonging to an item. Items and their values are in two different models related by a Foreignkey. I copied the inline_formset view as can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view) and it works fine. I am able to delete, update and create new entries.

However, I would like the possibility to add/edit/delete values dynamically and to this end I tried to use the [django-dynamic-formset jquery.](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset). When I refer to it in the template, and go to the view, I am able to add, and edit existing entires, yet I am not able to delete entires any more.

It seems that although the 'remove' function appears to work well, that is, it removes the lines from the html page, replaces the delete checkbox with a hidden input, sets the value for it to 'on' for lines removed, still, when to form is submitted, Django does not recognize any deleted items upon validation and saving. If I leave the checkboxes in, remove the jquery, everything works fine, except its not dynamic.

See below my template code:

```
<tbody>
              {{formset.management_form}}
              {% for szett_form in formset %}
              {{szett_form.id}}
              <tr class='inline'>
              <td>{% if formset.can_delete %}{{ szett_form.DELETE }}</td>{% endif %}
                <td >{{szett_form.intenzitas}}</td>
                <td>{{szett_form.ism}}</td>
                <td>{{szett_form.szett}}</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
      <div class="col lg-4">
        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
        </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.inline').formset({
    addText: 'add a set',
    deleteText: 'remove',
    prefix:'{{formset.prefix}}'
});
```

[This is how the rendered template looks with one table row removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE8QS.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE8QS.png)

Any ideas why this might be happening, is this an incompatibility with django-dynamic-formsets and django 2.0? Am i missing sth totally obvious? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

It looks like the problem is caused by 'value' parameter of the **input** tag not being rendered explicitly by django for the forms.booleanfield DELETE. Once the checkbox is checked without the jquery, and the form is submitted, it is interpreted as value=on for the delete in the background by the server. However, once the formset.jquery renames the input type to 'hidden' from 'checkbox' and ads value='on', it won't be recognized as value='on'by the server. I will check if this is the case with Django 1.11 as well. If yes, the only option might be to amend the formset.jquery to keep the checkbox and check it yet hide the row once "remove" is clicked.  I am open though to hear another solution.

***Update 2.***

The correct code in the template should be:

```
<tbody>
          {{formset.management_form}}
          {% for szett_form in formset %}
          <tr class='inline'>{{szett_form.id}}
          <td>{% if formset.can_delete %}{{ szett_form.DELETE }}</td>{% 
    endif %}
            <td >{{szett_form.intenzitas}}</td>
            <td>{{szett_form.ism}}</td>
            <td>{{szett_form.szett}}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Like I suspected, the problem was missing sth obvious. The form.id has to be put within the HTML tag referenced in the jquery script.

Comment: I leave it up here nevertheless, somone might get him/herself into a similar situation.

Comment: This was really helpful, I was going crazy why wasn't this working. Thanks!